# Armv7s in debug symbols only if pulled from recent device?

Tags: ios, xcode, debug-symbols

When symbolicating iOS crashes, scripts use iOS debug symbols that are stored in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport`. I've got a crash from iOS 7.1.2 (11D257) where all the lines in the module list but the actual executable have the **armv7s** architecture, like this:

```
0x30c8d000 - 0x30e77fff  Foundation armv7s  <52121842f9863ab49b775758dd05db0b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
```

I've got this very version of iOS under DeviceSupport, however, the system stackpoints fail to symbolicate; the script claims that none of the iOS files has the armv7s slice. Indeed, if I run

```
lipo -info '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.2 (11D257)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation'
```

it says that only **armv7** is present.

I've pulled the symbols from an iPhone 4; its CPU doesn't support armv7s. If you have an armv7s-capable device (iPhone 5+, iPad 3+) with iOS 7.1.2, can you please run the same command and confirm that the version of Foundation you have contains the armv7s slice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get armv7s iOS system symbols from devices with armv7s or arm64 CPU. The iPhone 4 has a armv7 CPU, so it obviously can't provide you with armv7s symbols.

Comment: Andreas Linde aka TheRealKerni, is that really you? I've pulled armv7s symbols from an iPhone 5, but symbolication results on a sample crash looks extremely bogus. I'm not sure what to blame - the symbolication script or the symbols.

Comment: Yes it is me. You only get symbols if you have them on your computer. If you have an issue understanding a symbolicated crash report, you might want to create a new question with all relevant details.

Comment: There is an issue indeed, but I see there QuincyKit 3.0 out there, with an updated symbolication script. Let me try with that one first...